# How is ci.mean.95 calculated in pastecs in r. Result not as expected

Tags: r, statistics, confidence-interval

I am using `pastecs` to get some descriptive statistics on a set of data.
I cannot understand how its `ci.mean.95` value is calculated.
As an example, if you do:

```
test <-c(1,2,3,4)
```

then

```
stat.desc(test)
```

you get

```
sum 10
mean 2.5
sd 1.2909944
se.mean 0.6454972
```

which all check out as expected, if I repeat the calculations on paper.
But, CI.mean.95 is 2.0542603  (it defaults to p 0.95)

When I do this calculation on paper it should be +/- 1.2651604

Can you say why these do not tally? What is stat.desc giving me with CI.mean if it is not the simple CI of the mean that I calculated?

I have poured over any info that comes with pastecs and can't see anything that explains why CI.mean.0.95 is not 1.96*SE.mean

Any insight into this would be very helpful, thanks.

Comment: Read the body of the function.

Answer (score 0):

If you type `stat.desc` and hit return, you'll see the body of the functions, as answered earlier.
It uses a t distribution for the confidence interval of the mean.

When you don't know the variance of the distribution and have to estimate it from the sample, a t distribution should be used, rather than a normal distribution [[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confidence_interval#Theoretical_example)].

We can see that `stat.desc` gives the correct answer:

```
    test <- c(1,2,3,4)
    (n <- length(test))
    [1]  4
    (se.mean <- sd(test)/sqrt(n))
    [1]  0.6454972
    (ci.mean.error <- qt(0.975, n-1)*se.mean)
    [1]  2.05426
```

While if we use a normal distribution:

```
    qnorm(0.975)*se.mean
    [1]  1.265151
    # Or:
    1.96*se.mean
    [1]  1.265175
```

For large sample sizes `qt(0.975, df)*se.mean` and `qnorm(0.975)*se.mean` gives similar results.